# jQuery UI Draggable Limits

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm making a draggable item, I just want this to drag vertically, limiting to the parent div, so its always completely visible, any suggestion?

http://jsfiddle.net/q3nz4/

```
<!--HTML Code-->
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;  background:#333;" id="dragable"></div>

<!--jQuery Code-->
$('#dragable').live('mouseover',function(){
   $(this).draggable();
});​
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/constrain-movement.html

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        axis: "y" 
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you told me how to, not just posting a link like in Yahoo Answers but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, here it is. $(function() { $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "y" });});

Comment: Oh, I havent seen it, please edit your answer with the comment code so I can vote up, it's locked, and notify here. thanks!